# PHP: seeking work-around for str_getcsv line-break bug inside quotation marks

Tags: php

I have a CSV like so:

```
Year,Make,Model,Description,Price
1997,Ford,E350,"ac, abs, moon",3000.00
1999,Chevy,"Venture ""Extended Edition""","",4900.00
1999,Chevy,"Venture ""Extended Edition, Very Large""","",5000.00
1996,Jeep,Grand Cherokee,"MUST SELL! ""TODAY""
air, moon roof, loaded",4799.00
```

**How can I convert it into a 2-dimensional array without the last line getting misplaced into its own array?**

---

Here is the illustration of the problem (also hosted here https://3v4l.org/HAJh1):

```
$s2=<<<EOD
Year,Make,Model,Description,Price
1997,Ford,E350,"ac, abs, moon",3000.00
1999,Chevy,"Venture ""Extended Edition""","",4900.00
1999,Chevy,"Venture ""Extended Edition, Very Large""","",5000.00
1996,Jeep,Grand Cherokee,"MUST SELL! ""TODAY""
air, moon roof, loaded",4799.00
EOD;

$lines=str_getcsv($s2,"\n");
print_r($lines);
```

And the bug in question (despite the PHP devs not recognizing it as one as of this writing): https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55763

There are ["solutions" out there](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php#101888), but none which seems to address this example.

Comment: You need to use `fgetcsv()`. If you read the file line-by-line and then use `str_getcsv()`, you won't have the next line in the string.

Comment: `str_getcsv()` expects the string to be just one record of the file, not the whole file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str_getcsv()` expects the string to be one CSV record, not the entire CSV file.

If you have the CSV file in memory, you can use `php://memory` to turn it into a stream that you can read with `fgetcsv()`. This will properly parse the records.

```
<?php
$s2=<<<EOD
Year,Make,Model,Description,Price
1997,Ford,E350,"ac, abs, moon",3000.00
1999,Chevy,"Venture ""Extended Edition""","",4900.00
1999,Chevy,"Venture ""Extended Edition, Very Large""","",5000.00
1996,Jeep,Grand Cherokee,"MUST SELL! ""TODAY""
air, moon roof, loaded",4799.00
EOD;
$stream = fopen("php://memory", "r+");
fwrite($stream, $s2);
rewind($stream);
while ($row = fgetcsv($stream)) {
  print_r($row);
}
```

If the CSV is actually in a file, just open the file and use `fgetcsv()` to read it as in the above.